# finding string in vector of uint8_t (in keil uvision5)

Tags: c++, string, vector, keil

i have created following code using keil uvision5.

```
// in .h
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <class T>
class RxPacket
{
private:        
    std::string idx_str;

public:
    RxPacket();     
    bool Rx_isQrcode(std::vector<T> in_pack);   
};

// in .cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <algorithm>
template class RxPacket<uint8_t>;

template <class T>
RxPacket<T>::RxPacket()
{
  idx_str = "TEST:";    
};

template <class T>
bool RxPacket<T>::Rx_isFound(std::vector<T> in_pack)
{   
   auto _idx = search(in_pack.begin(), in_pack.end(), idx_str.begin(),     
   idx_str.end());
   if(_idx == in_pack.end())
        return false;

   return true;
};
```

it works in VS. but in keil the error appears:
error:  #20: identifier "search" is undefined
        auto _idx = search(in_pack.begin(), in_pack.end(), idx_str.begin(), idx_str.end());

can you tell me how i can perform this error on this compiler.
or
is there another way for finding string in vector of uint8_t.

Comment: What about to add `#include<algorithm>` and then use it like  `std::search`, or a add `using namespace std;`

Comment: oh, yes. std:: is forgotten. but howVS works?

Comment: C++ looks up names by namespace of parameter types. For example when in_pack.begin() returns something that has type from namespace std then it looks up std::search because of that.